Inbox and reputation drop-downs occationally take me to my profile instead
In the top bar are these two buttons:



Some times they have red and green numbers on them, and I would like to see what that's about. Some times I want to get back to a recent (but already read) notification. At any rate, I rely on these buttons to activate a drop-down menu.
Some times that's not what happens when I click on them. Instead, (regardless of which network site I'm on) it takes me to my main site profile page https://stackexchange.com/users/887076/arthur (on the relevant tab depending on which of the two buttons I press).
I think it happens more often if I press before the page is fully loaded. But some times it doesn't help to wait. It happens on desktop and mobile alike.

Yeah, those buttons are regular links until all javascript is loaded and executed. After that the onClick event is handled and the normal behavior is prevented to execute. Pace yourself / resist the urge to click is probably the best advice ....

Makes sense. Then I guess my question changes to "If, once the page is loaded, these buttons are meant to act as buttons with an OnClick event and a dropdown, and not as a link, why are they coded as an actual link below that?" Unless there is some accessibility concern I'm not aware of or something.

It might be that they use the same buttons for the mobile view that doesn't have / had javascript.

"Then I guess my question changes to [...]" I guess partly graceful degradation. Even without JS you get some behaviour. Not the dynamic in-page one but you need JS for that. Also, I personally find it convenient that I can middle-click the button to get to the network profile page. Some times I may want to go to the network inbox and browse it, so having a one-click way to get there is convenient. If the link was entirely controlled via JS and non-functional otherwise, it'd have been more inconvenient.

No behaviour is certainly preferable to some, extremely annoying, behaviour.

The other buttons have similar behaviour: before a full page load the Review Queues button leads to the review page, and the 'Stack Exchange logo button' (how is that one actually called?) to stackexchange.com. The Help button leads to the /help page, IIRC. Very annoying behaviour - I'd rather they didn't do anything during that stage. I'm also pretty sure this isn't a bug, but status-by-design.
